# Change the keyboard shortcuts into emacs style for stack edit?

Tags: web-applications, stackedit

I am using the Google app called Stackedit. I am satisfied with every aspects of its features except keyboard shortcut, as I am more used to the C^f, C^b, C^n, C^p combinations that makes me a lot faster in moving cursor in the article. I just wonder has anybody extended the feature already or is there a more clear direction I should go to to add the feature myself.